# Show that series in Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a_n = d(p_n, p_n+1)$ for $n = 1, 2,\cdots $. Show that if the series $\displaystyle \sum^{∞}_{n=1} a_n$ converges, then $\{p_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

**My Approach:**

I thought of using the definition of Cauchy sequence to $p_n$ but I am not sure how to extract from $a_n$ information about $p_n$. Can someone help out?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: assume $m>n$. Applying the triangle inequality enough times, we get
$$
d(p_n,p_m)\leq d(p_n,p_{n+1})+d(p_{n+1},p_{n+2})+\cdots+d(p_{m-1},p_m)\leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k
$$